# Циклический сдвиг массива вправо не работает в stepik

Tags: c++

использую Dev-c++. У меня код работает как надо, а в степике код не работает и выдает ошибку:

Failed test #2. Runtime error
main: malloc.c:2406: sysmalloc: Assertion `(old_top == initial_top (av) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= MINSIZE && prev_inuse (old_top) && ((unsigned long) old_end & (pagesize - 1)) == 0)' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)

В чем причина? Не выход же за пределы массива?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    vector <int> a(n);

    //ввод
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        cin >> a[i];
    }

    //обработка
    int mem=a[n-1];    //сохранение последнего элемента вектора
    for (int i=n; i!=0; i--) { // массив сдвигается с конца
        swap(a[i],a[i-1]);     // сдвиг вправо на 1 элемент
    } 
    a[0]=mem; // замещение первого элемента последним до сдвига

    //вывод
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        cout << a[i] << " ";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

У вас тут через строчку выход за пределы массива. Вот перед циклом при `0 == n` выход  в `a[n-1]`; в цикле на первом же шаге, когда `i == n` выход в `a[i]`; затем при `0 == n` выход в `a[0]`

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, такой цикл сдвига должен начинаться с `i = n - 1`, а не c `i = n` (подразумевая, что размер массива - не нулевой). Это причина вашего сообщения об ошибке. Да, именно выход за пределы массива.

Во-вторых, разу уж вы собрались использовать внутри цикла именно `swap(a[i], a[i - 1])`, а не присваивание `a[i] = a[i - 1]`, то тогда вам совершенно не нужно запоминать последний элемент в `mem`, а затем записывать его в первый. Ваш цикл уже сам по себе реализует циклический сдвиг вправо. Все ваши манипуляции с `mem` - ненужная лишняя работа.

В "ручной" реализации уместнее было бы воспользоваться перемещающим конструированием/присваиванием, хотя в конкретном случае типа `int` это не принципиально

```
T mem = std::move(a[n - 1]);

for (auto i = n - 1; i > 0; --i)
  a[i] = std::move(a[i - 1]);

a[0] = std::move(mem);
```